# How do I stop Yahoo Sync?

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, mobileme, macos, yahoo

Since upgrading to Max OS X 10.7.2 and converting my MobileMe Account to iCloud I am receiving endless dialog boxes asking about syncing Yahoo Contacts.

I cannot find settings *anywhere* to turn this off. I have to manually dismiss these frakking dialogues, which come up at the rate of about one an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved this:

1. launch `Address Book`
2. go to `Preferences` -> `Accounts` tab -> `On My Mac` item
3. check `Synchronize with Yahoo!` box (which was unchecked for me)
4. choose `cancel` in the resulting dialogue box

I can only guess that checking `Synchronize with Yahoo!` and canceling the resulting dialogue shook some sense into some forgotten settings.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about this myself and started by looking in Activity Monitor, found that "launchd" was the service that kicked off the Yahoo Contacts Sync.  After some googl'ing I found out that custom scripts for launchd get executed from the ~(user)/Library/LaunchAgents folder.  In there, you'll find the culprit -- at least, I did.  Now I dunno if I should simply delete them (since I don't care about syncing contacts, I don't use the Mail.app) or if I can just disable it by tweaking the plist file.  Hope that helps!

EDIT: *I discovered that going into the AddressBook.app preferences and unchecking the accounts listed caused the plist files to be removed.  If you check them again, they reappear.  Works for me!  :)*

Answer (score 0):

Both Address Book and iTunes have (or had) UI for authenticating with Yahoo and enabling contact sync. When you migrated to iCloud, the UI probably went away.

One heavy-handed technique to solve this would be to remove `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/YahooSync.framework` from your system.

Comment: I think I must have overlooked the Yahoo! (yes, I am compelled to write it that way) syncing option in Address Book because its box was unchecked. But going through the preferences in Address Book and toggling the sync option from off (but not really off) -> on -> off was how I solved this.